# Error handling in Kotlin coroutines - How to display error on the UI?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

Apparently I have failed to understand the logic of exception handling with kotlin coroutines.
Could you please help me?
On my Android app I have a button which fires the fetch function.

This function does 3 things:

1. retrieves a json file from a server (getRequest) - might fail
2. Processes the json file (processJSON) and stores 4 values temporarily inside the instance of the class Departures (departures). - might fail for another reason
3. populates 4 TextView with those values. (uiUpdate)
   I would like all of those fields to be populated with one understandable error message generated by the catch clauses of these failed functions.
   How can I achieve this?

   ```
    fun fetch(stopID: String, attr: String, value: String) {
            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                try {
                    val result = getRequest(stopID)
                    val departures = processJSON(result, attr, value)
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {uiUpdate(stopID, departures)}
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                }
            }
        }
   ```

If I remove the try-catch here, the app crashes in case of an exception.
If I put the uiUpdate into the shown catch clause it crashes again.

Answer (score 2):

By default `lifecycleScope` uses [`Dispatchers.Main.immediate`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-main-coroutine-dispatcher/immediate.html) dispatcher. You can remove `Dispatchers.IO` from passing it to `lifecycleScope.launch` and just call `suspend` functions, wrapped into `try-catch`:

```
 fun fetch(stopID: String, attr: String, value: String) = lifecycleScope.launch {
         try {
             val result = getRequest(stopID)
             val departures = processJSON(result, attr, value)
             uiUpdate(stopID, departures)
         } catch (e: Exception) {
             // You can update UI here as well
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Sergey! The following function really does what I intended to achieve.
I removed the try-catch from inside the functions and added the respective @Throws expressions before the declaration of these functions.

```
 fun fetch(stopID: String, attr: String, value: String) {
          lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
              try {
                 val result = getRequest(stopID)
                 val departures = processJSON(result, attr, value)
                 withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {uiUpdate(stopID, departures)}
             } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
                  withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {uiUpdate(stopID, Departures("Error2","Error2"))}
             } catch (e: JSONException) {
                  withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {uiUpdate(stopID, Departures("Error3","Error3"))}
             } catch (e: Exception) {
                 withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {uiUpdate(stopID, Departures("Error4","Error4"))}
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can remove all `withContext(Main)` if you remove the dispatcher from the `launch` call. It will be used by default. If you really need `getRequest` and/or `processJSON` to run on other dispatchers, you could wrap *them* in `withContext` with the dispatcher you want. Note that `withContext` returns the value of the last expression in the lambda, so you can get a result out of it: `val departures = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { processJSON(...) }`